# Change paper size when using pdfx

Tags: geometry, pdfx

I have the following MWE

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}
\usepackage[x-1a,pdf13]{pdfx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{%
    paperwidth=96mm,
    paperheight=96mm,
    margin=3mm,
}
\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

where I would like to set the paper size as specified by the geometry macro. This works as expected when commenting out the `\usepackage{pdfx}` line, but I need to build a PDF/X-1a document with this paper size.

Does anyone know how to get pdfx working together with non standard paper sizes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load pdfx later:

```
\documentclass[cmyk]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\geometry{%
    paperwidth=96mm,
    paperheight=96mm,
    margin=3mm,
}
\usepackage[x-1a,pdf13]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```