# How can pdfx and crop package work together in one document?

Tags: pdftex, pdfx

This is still a question related to the book to be published. The printer requires PDF/X-4 for the PDF and hence I am trying to include `pdfx` into it. However as we also need to include crop marks, `crop` is also part of the game.

However no matter in which order I try to include those to packages, the page size always defaults to the original size set in `scrbook`. The only thing related I found was [Change paper size when using pdfx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472878/change-paper-size-when-using-pdfx) but this is of no help here.

```
\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot,10pt,paper=155mm:230mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[frame,width=169.8truemm,height=247.4truemm,cam,pdftex,cross]{crop}
\setlength{\voffset}{7.4mm}
\setlength{\hoffset}{7.4mm}

\usepackage[x-4]{pdfx}

\usepackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout
{\ifodd\value{page}
    \pdfpageattr{%
        /BleedBox [20.976 19.843 468.850 688.819]
        /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
        /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 481.323 701.291]
    }
    \else 
    \pdfpageattr{%
        /BleedBox [12.472 19.843 460.346 688.819]
        /TrimBox [20.976 28.346 460.346 680.315]
        /MediaBox [0.000 0.000 481.323 701.291]
    }
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
It seems, that pdfx and crop don't work well together, no matter in which order they are called, because:

This page is too small
\newpage
And this page is too small, too
\end{document}
```

If you check the resulting PDF, then it contains the following section at the end:

```
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 2
/Kids [5 0 R 10 0 R]
/MediaBox[0 0 439.369 651.9669]
 /BleedBox[0 0 439.369 651.9669]
 /CropBox[0 0 439.369 651.9669]
 /TrimBox[25 20 414.369 631.9669]
>>
```

If you manually delete all the boxes, then the page looks exactly as I want it to look in Adobe Reader. What can I do to achieve this behaviour out of the box/automatically without manual fiddling?

The issue seems to be in lines 496-502 of pdfx.sty:

```
  \edef\next{\endgroup\pdfpagesattr{%
    /MediaBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
%%    /ArtBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
    /BleedBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
    /CropBox[0 0 \pdfx@mwidth\space \pdfx@mheight]^^J
    /TrimBox[25 20 \pdfx@twidth\space \pdfx@theight]}
  }\next
```

But I don't know what to do here to prevent this writeout and still get a valid PDF/X-4?

Comment: I would avoid to use pdfx and add what ever you need for pdf/x yourself in this case. pdfx has very specific views about which options to use and overruling them is not easy.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem for a long time and finally found a simple hack that seems to work. Just before `\begin{document}` add

```
\pdfpagesattr{}
```

My understanding is that the `standalone` class or some other mechanism adds the first `/MediaBox` which we want and then `pdfx` adds the rest of `/MediaBox`, `/BleedBox` etc. through `\pdfpagesattr` which, as you identified, are incorrect. Luckily the `\pdfpagesattr` command can be reused to clear those unnecessary statements.