# How can I avoid that PGF writes a RGB reference into my PDF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I am still in the process of preparing a print ready PDF. For this I am trying to convert everything in my file to CMYK and hence I am searching the PDF output for any reference to RGB. One thing puzzles me, given a very simple file

```
\pdfcompresslevel0
\pdfobjcompresslevel0
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    Test
\end{document}
```

already contains a reference to RGB in the PDF:

```
<<  /pgfprgb [/Pattern /DeviceRGB] >>
```

I think this is due to the code in `pgfsys-pdftex.def` but I do not know how to suppress this or replace it. Obviously `/pgfprgb` is not part of my resulting PDF, because I am not drawing with TikZ (also not in my original file, I only use TikZ for absolute positioning.

So maybe it is easier to use absolute positioning without TikZ instead of fiddling around with a hack.

Comment: Why do you want to suppress it? It is not used but only sitting around in the resources.

Comment: My fear is, that this will create a non-compliance to the PDF/X-4 standard, which is required by the printer. However I cannot really check, because I have no Adobe Acrobat to verify. Remember my question from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546953/how-can-pdfx-and-crop-package-work-together-in-one-document