# package clash of zwpagelayout, pdfx and scrlayer-scrpage: TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: koma-script, pdfx, cropmarks

If use `pdflatex` on the minimal (non-)working example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[onlycropmarks,croptitle={~}]{zwpagelayout}
\usepackage[x-4]{pdfx}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

in pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) i get:

```
./mwe.tex:8: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.8 \end{document}
```

I already tried permutations of the order: But the only difference, I got, was:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[onlycropmarks,croptitle={~}]{zwpagelayout}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

This results (even without loading `pdfx`) in:

```
./mwe.tex:6: Package scrlayer Error: package incompatibility detected.
```

Is it possible to use all three packages (with the given options) together? If yes, how?

Comment: no, zwpagelayout and scrlayer are not compatible.  Why do you want to use zwpagelayout?

Comment: I want to prepare a book for the printer guys. Some pages contain full-page images (no border). So I guess, I need a trimming edge ("Beschnittrand").

Comment: use the crop package.

Comment: That's what I tried 5 years ago, but failed, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387876/packages-crop-and-pdfx-result-in-cropped-pages
crop and pdfx seem to have problems, too.
Maybe I did something wrong last time?
However, I might have found a solution for that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546953/how-can-pdfx-and-crop-package-work-together-in-one-document

Comment: depending on what you want from pdfx you can use the new pdfmanagement instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the above example is that the packages `scrlayer-scrpage` and `zwpagelayout` are not compatible, see [above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698428/package-clash-of-zwpagelayout-pdfx-and-scrlayer-scrpage-tex-capacity-exceeded#comment1735412_698428).

If you just want to add crop marks to your document, you can replace `zwpagelageout` with `crop`.

When using `crop` and `pdfx` together, this might leed to a new (layout) problem. However, that can be solved by adding `\pdfpagesattr{}`, see [How can pdfx and crop package work together in one document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/546953/how-can-pdfx-and-crop-package-work-together-in-one-document)

So a fixed version of the above code could be:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[x-4]{pdfx}
\usepackage[cam,width=230mm,height=317mm,center]{crop}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pdfpagesattr{}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but it isn't a great idea when your answer is basically the content of the comments you received. I'd suggest asking one of the people commenting if they want to write an answer. If they say no or don't respond in a reasonable time, then creating a `community wiki` answer would be a reasonable solution. In this case, I'd suggest asking Ulrike Fischer what to do at this point.

Comment: I didn't even know there's a wiki here.
Maybe you didn't see the whole story:
~5 years ago I asked, because A didn't work, #387876. Somebody recommended B.
Now I had new problems with B and Ulrike Fischer recommended to use A, so a semantical loop began. :-)
Meanwhile #387876 was deleted. However, somebody else had the same problem and got an answer C at #546953 which also helps with my problem. It's not a duplicate, because the _problem_ is different.
In my answer I summarize the background knowledge and explanations and gave a working solution. It's not just a copy of an answer.